# Mark users coming to website from my application

Tags: c#, http, web-analytics, matomo

My application has some menu buttons that sends the users to my website.

I want to differentiate in the website how many users came from my app, out of all the regular users.

My app is written in C#, and currently I direct users like this:

```
string url = "http://mysite/somepage";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

On the server side, I use [Piwik](http://www.piwik.org) for my web paralytics.

Any suggestions?

---

**Update**

One good solution will be to add some parameter to the URL. Yet I was wondering if it's possible to play with the referrer field, for the sake paralytics simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add something to the url, probably in the querystring that identifies that the user has originated from your application, like:

```
string url = "http://mysite/somepage?source=myApplication";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

You can/could also use this to track the versions of your app that are in use by adding more to the url, for example *?source=myApplication&version=1.0.3* =)

Comment: that's simple enough... tnx. I thought about adding some fake referrer. is that possible? (will be separated nicer in my piwik)

Comment: All you're doing is passing the URL off to the system which will open the browser; you have no control of the Referer header.  The URL is simpler and more reliable (e.g. proxies that could potentially alter or remove the referrer).

Answer (score 2):

Just add a parameter to the URL coming from your app, other users will not have that:

```
string url = "http://mysite/somepage?fromApp=v1";
```

On your website, you can pick that up to differentiate users. Do a redirect immediately after, so they will not bookmark the page with this URL.

Comment: that's simple enough... tnx. I thought about adding some fake referrer. is that possible? (will be separated nicer in my piwik)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add some parameter to the URL your application is using and use that to filter users coming from your app?

Comment: I could. I thought about using referrer, not sure if it's too complicated.